# Edge detection on depth image

Tags: compositing-nodes, depth-map

I have a 3d model and I want to apply an edge detection to the depth-image of the current viewport. I thought this might be possible with the composite tool. At least if offers a laplace and sobel filter as a node. I only have to get the depths image into that node, I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: For want of a quick peek at the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/filter_node.html), you've pretty much answered your own question! :)